# How can I get the Ajax extensions to show in VS2008 IDE

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

When I open a 3.5 related web project then the Ajax extension is showing; e.g.: script manager, update panel etc

However when I open a 2.0 web project then Ajax extension is not showing.

Please guide me on what to do if I want Ajax extension to be available in case of 2.0 related project.

Do I need to download an installer? If so then please tell me URL from where I can download Ajax extension for 2.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to get the ajax extensions for .NET 2.0
[Download](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=77296)

Comment: I was about to answer the same thing when I read the question, then noticed you already got it :-).

Comment: thanks but u did not mention that how ajax extension will be added in VS2005 toolbar after installing this exe. do i need to do anything to make it available to toolbar or it will automatically available after installation. please explain.......thanks a lot. :)

Comment: right click on a blank area in the toolbar, click "add tab" then call it "AJAX 2.0 Extensions", right click again, this time within the tab you just created, select "choose items" and then browse to the ajax extensions for .net 2.0 dll (included in the download above).